# Converter String em data e remover 1 dia dessa String

Tags: php, data, conversão-de-tipo

Eu tenho essa string:

```
$data_final = "26/11/2017";
```

E eu preciso que essa variável fique como `25/11/2017`. Ou seja, preciso converter string em data e remover 1 dia dessa data.

Comment: `echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-1 days', strtotime('26-11-2017')));`

Comment: Esse código não funcionou, ele mostrou 31/12/1969

Comment: @FelipeMorenoBorges   dê uma olhada na minha resposta. Você testá tentando com a data no formato brasileiro ou americano?

Comment: @FelipeMorenoBorges a resposta do RSantos agora tá certa. Vale a pena dar uma olhadinha também.

Comment: @FelipeMorenoBorges alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Se sim marque a mesma como correta para facilitar aos próximos que possam ter a mesma dúvida a encontrar a resposta mais facilmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o método `DateTime::createFromFormat`. Através desse método é possível criar um objeto `DateTime` a partir de qualquer formato. Em seguida, tendo o objeto criado usamos o método `modify`, que aceita como parâmetro os mesmos valores que `strtotime`. No final, usamos o método `format` para obter a data no formato desejado.

Veja:

```
$data_final = '26/11/2017';

$ontem = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data_final)->modify('-1 day');

echo $ontem->format('d/m/Y');
```

Veja um exemplo rodando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/4dQiaG)

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!

Comment: @FelipeMorenoBorges Que bom, cara! considere marcar como "aceito" a resposta que resolveu seu problema

Comment: @FelipeMorenoBorges se a resposta resolveu o seu problema marque-a como correta por favor. Se não sabe como fazer leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635

Answer (score 4):

```
$data = '26/11/2017';

$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
$data->sub(new DateInterval('P1D')); // -1 dia
echo $data->format('d/m/Y');
```

Utilizei o `sub` para remover a quantidade de dias necessária, conteúdo **[AQUI](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.sub.php)**

Resumidamente o `P` simboliza o período, o `1` a quantidade do período a remover e o `D` simboliza dias.

Comment: Esse código não funcionou, ele mostrou 31/12/1969

Comment: Sua resposta tem um probleminha: O AP pediu no formato d/m/Y, e não no formato americano. Deve ter sido esse o erro.

Comment: @R.Santos só edita ela e corrija. Assim os negativos podem ser removidos e a resposta vai ajudar o AP.  Isso aqui seria uma boa opção: https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_date_create_from_format.asp

Comment: @WallaceMaxters ajustei a resposta conforme outro conteúdo que encontrei o que você acha?

Comment: @R.Santos ficou ótimo. testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente. Vou retirar o -1 e te dar um upvote.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Ah que ótimo então :)

Answer (score -1):

Se garantir que a variável virá sempre com o formato xx/xx/xxxx pode simplesmente usar o [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) seguido de [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$data_final = explode("/","26/11/2017");

var_dump($data_final);

$data_final[0]--;

echo $data_final[0];

$data_final = implode("/",$data_final);

var_dump($data_final);
```

Mas aconselho a usar a solução dada pelo camarada R.Santos

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-1 days', strtotime('26-11-2017')));
```

Comment: O mesmo problema da resposta anterior. O AP pediu no formato `d/m/Y` (Brasileiro) e não no formato americano. Sendo assim, sua resposta não se aplica a pergunta.